# Replace anchor tag with span tag

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I have created my custom menu having many items and sub items, the markup is like this `<a href="#">Item</a>`but for parent element I need to replace anchor tag with the span tag having some class for styling purpose, only for my parent elements. It should be like this, `<span class="my-class">Parent Element</span>`. Can any one please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code added to your themes `functions.php` will do what you want.

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4 );
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    if ( empty( $item->url ) || '#' === $item->url ) {
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<span class="my-class">';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</span>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
    }
    return $item_output;
}
```

This should find all menu items with no URL or `#` as the URL and replace the link with `<span class="my-class">...</span>`.

This wouldn't specifically apply to parent menu items, but as long as you use a custom link and don't enter a URL (or you enter a `#`) for your parent menu items then it should work for you.

Comment: how to change this code that replace a to span for elements who has sub menu?